# How to run nginx in background and sleep in foreground in a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, nginx, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine-slim
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ping.url /
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache sudo curl busybox-extras bind-tools nmap-ncat openssl netcat-openbsd openssh git && \
    echo "nginx is up."  > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && \
    adduser -u 1000 -D chip && \
    echo "chip:123" | chpasswd && \
    echo "chip ALL=(ALL) ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/chip && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/chip && \
    nginx -g "daemon on;"
USER 1000
ENTRYPOINT [ "sleep", "infinity" ]
```

However, there is no background nginx process.

This image is running on a k8s pod, when I exec into the pod I can run nginx in the background no problem:

```
mark@L-R910LPKW:~/chip/toolbox-app/src [test ≡]$ k exec deployments/toolbox -c toolbox -it -- sh
/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 chip      0:00 sleep infinity
   16 chip      0:00 sh
   22 chip      0:00 ps
/ $ sudo nginx -g "daemon on;"

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for chip:
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 23#23: using the "epoll" event method
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 23#23: nginx/1.23.3
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 23#23: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 23#23: OS: Linux 5.4.0-1103-azure
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 23#23: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 24#24: start worker processes
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 25
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 26
/ $ 2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 27
2023/04/01 16:08:03 [notice] 24#24: start worker process 28

/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 chip      0:00 sleep infinity
   16 chip      0:00 sh
   24 root      0:00 nginx: master process nginx -g daemon on;
   25 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   26 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   27 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   28 nginx     0:00 nginx: worker process
   29 chip      0:00 ps
/ $
```

And the nginx daemon continues running when I leave the container.

So why does it not run initially? I must be botching the Dockerfile, but where?

**EDIT 1**

I know I can run nginx in the foreground. I specifically do not want it. One of the reasons is that I want the default user in the container to be a non root user of my chosing, not the root. I know I can run unprivileged version of nginx too.

But I want to stick to the regular nginx image as the base, let it run in the background and run sleep in the foreground as a non root user. Surely it is possible?

**EDIT 2**

Allow me to add the rationale. My requirement was to create an image that hosts a simple web server that just responds to a single url and packs some tools for troubleshooting problems with pod communication.

So, my original Dockerfile was this one:

```
FROM nginx:1.23.3-alpine-slim
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache curl busybox-extras bind-tools nmap-ncat openssl netcat-openbsd && \
    echo "nginx is up."  > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ping.url /
```

Where nginx.conf is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

And that works great.

But then I decided I want to have a container running under a non root account. And faced a problem.

An easy solution would be to switch to the unprivileged nginx image, i.e. something like this:

```
FROM nginxinc/nginx-unprivileged:1.23.3-alpine-slim
USER 0
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ping.url /
ARG chip_user_pwd
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache sudo curl busybox-extras bind-tools nmap-ncat openssl netcat-openbsd openssh git && \
    echo "nginx is up."  > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && \
    adduser -u 1000 -D chip && \
    echo "chip:$chip_user_pwd" | chpasswd && \
    echo "chip ALL=(ALL) ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/chip && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/chip
USER 101
```

But I am curious whether it is the only solution. Because suppose nginx did not have the unprivileged alternative. What would have people do to make it work? I want to learn. Now a possible answer could be - nothing, it just does not work. But I do not have enough knowledge in the containerization domain to reach this conclusion on my own.

Comment: Have you tried `CMD sudo nginx -g "daemon on;" & sleep infinity` ?

Comment: No, I have not. I will try.

Comment: Nope, nginx is not running, because sudo asks for the password. It shows in the logs

Comment: Why do you want a container that does nothing, but that you'd have to manually administer?  You mention Kubernetes here; how will you deal with multiple replicas of a container, or when a Pod gets replaced on routine upgrades, or if the cluster deletes and replaces a Pod because a node is being shut down?  Things like the user ID can be specified in the Deployment spec.  I'd recommend deleting the `ENTRYPOINT` line and running Nginx as the single foreground process in the container.

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 2**. Does it make more sense now?

Answer (score 1):

RUN directive is for build time. So the last line just run in build time.

```
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache sudo curl busybox-extras bind-tools nmap-ncat openssl netcat-openbsd openssh git && \
    echo "nginx is up."  > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html && \
    adduser -u 1000 -D chip && \
    echo "chip:123" | chpasswd && \
    echo "chip ALL=(ALL) ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/chip && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/chip && \
    nginx -g "daemon on;"
```

You could add the process in background like [mentioned](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/7f1ef355dea083761951da16ab02ea2c37addbdd/stable/alpine-slim/Dockerfile#L121) in the official `Dockerfile`

```
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**Response to EDIT1**

*OPTION1*

Change `ENTRYPOINT` to this:

```
ENTRYPOINT  [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "nginx; sleep infinity"]
```

*OPTION2*

Create a sample `entrypoint.sh` file like:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
nginx
sleep infinity
```

And these lines and remove the `ENTRYPOINT`:

```
ADD entry.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entry.sh
CMD [ "/entry.sh"]
```

Comment: Please, see EDIT 1.

Comment: Updated. See if it helped, please.

Comment: How do I remove the ENTRYPOINT? It is defined inside the base image. I know I can override it, but how do I remove it?

Comment: Check again. Please also remove `nginx -g "daemon on;"` from the RUN.

Comment: How would it run nginx if the current user is non root? And `sudo` asks for the password?

Comment: You could run as non root user, but you need to add some changes to your Dockerfile.
https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged/blob/main/mainline/alpine-slim/Dockerfile

Comment: I am fine to add changes.

Comment: What is wrong with the `nginx-unprivileged`? It is exactly what you want.

Comment: Nothing, I am just curious if it can be done without it in hope to learn valuable techniques.